# Can't Declare friend for Typedef

Tags: c++, typedef, friend

I have the following :

```
typedef SP<CVPatModel *> VModel;


class VLIB_API CVPatModel
{
public :

    friend VModel;

protected :

    virtual void Save( char* szFileName );

}


void CTest::SaveModelToFile( VModel ModelPtr, char* szFileName )
{

    ModelPtr->Save(szFileName);
}
```

I will get "cannot access protected member declared in class 'CVPatModel'".

Is there anyway for me to access Save() through VModel?

Thank you!

Comment: Make CTest::SaveModelToFile() a friend of SP<>.

Comment: SP<> is a general smart pointer class, so I can't make CTest::SaveModelToFile() a friend of it.

Comment: did my answer work for you? if not, please help me improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to mess around with the internals of the smart pointer class, because `ModelPtr->` yields a `CVPatModel*`. Because your class `CTest` does not know about `CVPatModel`'s `protected` member `Save()`, you have to declare `CTest::SaveModelToFile` a `friend` of `CVPatModel`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using SP = std::shared_ptr<T>;

class CVPatModel;
typedef SP<CVPatModel> VModel;

class CTest
{
public:
    void SaveModelToFile( VModel ModelPtr, const char* szFileName );    
};  

class CVPatModel
{
public : 
    friend void CTest::SaveModelToFile( VModel, const char*);

protected : 
    virtual void Save( const char* szFileName ) { std::cout << "saving to file \"" << szFileName << "\" succeeded!\n"; };
};

void CTest::SaveModelToFile( VModel ModelPtr, const char* szFileName )
{ 
    ModelPtr->Save(szFileName);
}

int main()
{
    VModel vm = std::make_shared<CVPatModel>();
    CTest ct;
    ct.SaveModelToFile(vm, "bla");
}
```

Output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/DVtspL).

If you start adding many more test functions to `CTest`, you might as well put a `friend class CTest` inside your `CVPatModel`.